# While compile on simulator the cordova code in Xcode 12.2 with MFP getting error for arm64

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins, xcode12, mfp

I have a project cordova with the MFP plugin & while compile or build on the simulator the Xcode project in Xcode ver 12.2 getting below error.

Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file '.../Frameworks/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.framework/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation' for architecture arm64

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Build Settings of the project, locate the VALID_ARCHS property of User-Defined, and add x86_64. As shown below.

[image]